# What's the name of the first ending and second opening song of Hu Yao Xiao Hong Niang (Fox Spirit Matchmaker)?

Tags: hu-yao-xiao-hong-niang

Unfortunately, this "anime" is from China and there're no subtitles for the information shown during the openings and endings. I've already searched a lot on google to find any traces, but I didn't succeed.

Does anybody know the name of the first ending and second opening song?

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UahrVMd2vAY&list=PLSkNsC52FdsoLUmxU_vdK1_x2wvic9qgr&index=1)'s the link (it redirects you to a YouTube video) for the **ending song** starting at *13:01* and **second opening song** starting at *1:56*.

Edit: the video on YouTube seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are watching this show, I assume that you know Chinese and can read it. Therefore, I consider it unusual that you did not just google the name of the show and look for its Baidu Baike Page, China's Wikipedia equivalent. Anyway, here is the page for that show. [LINK](http://baike.baidu.com/subview/9363221/17967316.htm?from=qqvideo#10_1)

This page has the name for all the show's openings and endings, even the insert songs.

Here are Youtube links for each OP and ED. Btw, OP 1 really is just 1.30 long, it is already the full version.

OP 1: [爱You Ready爱我 Ready](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FAKzj6U6rwA)

OP 2: [梦回还](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DAtMJq74xbk)

ED 1: [東流](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RfVUUGxdi_A)

Insert Song: [相聚万年树](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xac7QWg3gQE)

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm only capable of speaking Chinese, but I've never learned to write or read.

Comment: @Eti2d1 Enjoy the songs. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

From what I'm understanding the first one is called, "If The Afterlife" in English and the second translates to, Dream Back Also."